# How to autoresize my UIcollectionView Frame in Stack View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uistackview

I have textField, pickerView, and collectionView in stackView. However, my CollectionView seems out of bound? How to make my UICollectionView autoresize based on how much UICollectionViewCell it has? Eg. If I have 15 cells, so I expect the UICollectionView to be huge.

Screenshot:
my UICollectionView seems out of bound

[image]

Comment: Cells will bear added dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself. You will need a height constraint for your collection view, observe number of cells or data (whenever it changes), adjust that height constraint.

Comment: how to do that? I've tried nearly all posibility of the constraint but didn't get what I really want. I even make individual height equal to 30, and set picker view height to 70, but however, when I contraint the height of the uicollection view, it turn out the first text Field to become so widen up.

Comment: Then the constraints have problem as well. We can't solve this by just look at the screenshot, you need to provide more details of what you did.

I recommend you take a look at this tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

and also look for Content hugging priority and Content compress resistance priority.